# Adding a form to pre existing Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, bitcoin

Please excuse the vague title. What I am actually attempting is to add another tab to a Cryptocurrency wallet based on Bitcoin code but I am a bit new to Qt and I have come across an error I can't fix.

I have created the form in Qt Designer and used uic to turn it into .h file and referenced that in the bitcoingui.cpp/.h and Project.pro files.

The generated .h can be found here: [radio.h](http://hastebin.com/ihozanifod.coffee)

bitcoingui.cpp here: [bitcoingui.cpp](http://hastebin.com/evajazesaz.coffee)

bitcoingui.h here: [bitcoingui.h](http://hastebin.com/uviqemadex.scala)

The error in question is:

```
src/qt/bitcoingui.cpp: In constructor ‘BitcoinGUI::BitcoinGUI(QWidget*)’:
src/qt/bitcoingui.cpp:119: error: no matching function for call to ‘Ui_Radio::Ui_Radio(BitcoinGUI* const)’
src/qt/radio.h:15: note: candidates are: Ui_Radio::Ui_Radio()
src/qt/radio.h:15: note:                 Ui_Radio::Ui_Radio(const Ui_Radio&)

src/qt/bitcoingui.cpp:129: error: no matching function for call to ‘QStackedWidget::addWidget(Ui_Radio*&)’
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qstackedwidget.h:67: note: candidates are: int QStackedWidget::addWidget(QWidget*)

src/qt/bitcoingui.cpp: In member function ‘void BitcoinGUI::gotoRadioPage()’:
src/qt/bitcoingui.cpp:781: error: no matching function for call to ‘QStackedWidget::setCurrentWidget(Ui_Radio*&)’
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qstackedwidget.h:80: note: candidates are: void QStackedWidget::setCurrentWidget(QWidget*)
src/qt/bitcoingui.cpp:785: error: no matching function for call to ‘BitcoinGUI::connect(QAction*&, const char [13], Ui_Radio*&, const char [17])’
/opt/local/include/QtCore/qobject.h:215: note: candidates are: static bool QObject::connect(const QObject*, const char*, const QObject*, const char*, Qt::ConnectionType)
/opt/local/include/QtCore/qobject.h:229: note:                 static bool QObject::connect(const QObject*, const QMetaMethod&, const QObject*, const QMetaMethod&, Qt::ConnectionType)
/opt/local/include/QtCore/qobject.h:338: note:                 bool QObject::connect(const QObject*, const char*, const char*, Qt::ConnectionType) const
make: *** [build/bitcoingui.o] Error 1
```

Which tells me that there are issues with line 119, 129, 781 and 785 in my bitcoingui.cpp

The lines in question are:

```
radioPage = new Ui_Radio(this);
centralWidget->addWidget(radioPage);
centralWidget->setCurrentWidget(radioPage);
connect(exportAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), radioPage, SLOT(exportClicked()));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What's wrong?

A valid Widget in Qt contains two parts:

- **Logic** (`Radio.h`):  Header file that depicted the class.
- **UI** (`UI_Radio.h`):  Generated from `.ui` by UIC. Usually, Qt's UIC use prefix `UI_` to denote the difference from another header file. This header file just define a class to conveniently manage UI components, it's not a widget itself, just a normal C++ class.

In your case, I think your `Radio` class should be a `QWidget`. It means in `Radio.h` you will at least have an explicitly defined constructor which assigns the parent widget. Besides, in `Radio.cpp` you will call `setupUi` to link the class and the UI (from `UI_Radio.h`).

**So this is what you should do:**

[image]

**But this is what you have done** ( You used the name `Radio.h` here, but it doesn't matter ):

[image]

> So your problem is: **You didn't even implement the Radio class**, while
>   you should've made it a valid widget.

Take a look at your [`Radio.h`](http://hastebin.com/ihozanifod.coffee) file (normally named as `UI_Radio.h`), there is no any constructor defined explicitly. That's why you got this error:

```
src/qt/bitcoingui.cpp: In constructor ‘BitcoinGUI::BitcoinGUI(QWidget*)’:
src/qt/bitcoingui.cpp:119: error: no matching function for call to ‘Ui_Radio::Ui_Radio(BitcoinGUI* const)’
```

The Qt Designer cannot build a whole widget for you. It just help you create the layout of the widget, and you still need to implement the logic part of the widget.

I would suggest you take a look at `overviewPage` to see how a widget should be implemented before it can be added to the main window.

---

## Explanation of Errors

Your lines in questions:

**Line 119**

```
radioPage = new Ui_Radio(this);
```

`this` point to `BitcoinGUI`, which is a widget. You failed to instantiate your `Radio` class here.

**Line 129 & 781**

```
centralWidget->addWidget(radioPage);
centralWidget->setCurrentWidget(radioPage);
```

Your `radioPage` has already failed to instantiate. Besides, it's not even a valid widget at all. Hence these two setters failed, take it for granted.

**Line 785**

```
connect(exportAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), radioPage, SLOT(exportClicked()));
```

`connect` function only works for `QObject`, which `QWidget` inherits from. There is no doubt your `radioPage` failed here again.

Comment: Hey,

okay so I managed to implement it as a widget and the webpage I wanted loaded great using webView.

The webpage in question is an internet radio page which I can't seem to get to play. The audio stream works in the example Qt browser so I know it's possible but I don't know how to implement audio. Do you have any pointers?

Thanks again!

Comment: @MystPhysX If you have another question, feel free to click `Ask Question` and start a new post. This question is deemed resolved and it's hard for you to get any further attention by leaving a comment here. I would suggest you just ask a new question, after all this is how StackOverflow works.